# ajax function is not working in ROR 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have save data in table through ajax, now I want to get data in json format.. How can i do this?

```
def feedback
    @FeedbackComment = FeedbackComment.new(params[:FeedbackComment])
    if @FeedbackComment.save
        format.json  { render :layout =>false, :msg=>"comment oooK" }
         render :nothing => true
        #format.json { render :layout => false, :text => 1 } 
    else

        #format.json { render :layout => false, :text => 2 }
         render :nothing => true
    end
      #render :nothing => true
end
```

In this function data is save but when i get error in format.json what worng in this

```
http://localhost:3001/feedback_comments/feedback
```

error : ArgumentError in FeedbackCommentsController#feedback

what can i do this to do this

Answer (score 0):

You are making json call and then rendering nothing. this is not the way.
Remove render :nothing => true and Add format.js under format.json. you method should look like

```
def feedback
  @FeedbackComment = FeedbackComment.new(params[:FeedbackComment])
  if @FeedbackComment.save
    format.json
    format.js
  end
end
```

Now if you want to go ahead then create feedback.js.erb file in views//

For more detail please check

[Ajax with rjs](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/43-ajax-with-rjs)

[Rjs Tips](http://railscasts.com/episodes/45-rjs-tips)

[working_with_javascript_in_rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

[getting-ajax rails 3](http://keithschacht.com/getting-ajax-to-work-in-rails-3-with-jquery/)